# Increase the number of reported Javadoc errors and warning when building with Maven

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am using Maven to build a project which has somewhat suboptimal Javadoc comments.

I have noticed that no matter how many warnings I fix, I always get only 100 warnings reported:

```
Building index for all the packages and classes...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\overview-tree.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\index-all.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\deprecated-list.html...
Building index for all classes...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\allclasses-frame.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\allclasses-frame.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\allclasses-noframe.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\allclasses-noframe.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\index.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\overview-summary.html...
Generating ...\target\site\apidocs\help-doc.html...
100 errors
100 warnings
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to see all of the errirs and warnings or at least the total count.

How do I achieve this with Maven?

Answer (score 4):

I have finally found the following configuration to work:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <additionalJOptions>
        <additionalJOption>-Xmaxerrs</additionalJOption>
        <additionalJOption>65536</additionalJOption>
        <additionalJOption>-Xmaxwarns</additionalJOption>
        <additionalJOption>65536</additionalJOption>
      </additionalJOptions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

It basically passes `-Xmaxerrs 65536` and `-Xmaxwarns 65536` (as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javadoc.htm)) to `javadoc`.

Answer (score 0):

this works also to (nearly) switching off the warnings, by setting it to 1

```
<configuration>
  <additionalJOptions>
    <additionalJOption>-Xmaxwarns</additionalJOption>
    <additionalJOption>1</additionalJOption>
  </additionalJOptions>
</configuration>
```